# How to fix this crash relating to the dynamic array pointer/ stack in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack using array pointer. When the stack is full, it expands twice of its original size. When the number of elements stored in the stack is half size of the stack, it shrinks in half. Push works fine. The problem is pop. When I put testSize in pop, the program crashes (See balded lines). Can anyone help me find me to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

double* initialize(int* top)
{
    *top=0;
    return (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*2);
}
// add a new value to the top of the stack (if not full)
void push(double* stack, int* top, const double new_value, int *stack_size)
{
    *(stack+*top)=new_value;
    ++*top;
    testSize(stack,stack_size,top);
}
// remove (and return) the value at the top of the stack (if not empty)
double pop(double* stack, int* top,int* stack_size)
{
    **//testSize(stack,stack_size,top);**
    if(*top)
    {
        int temp=--*top;
        double result= *(stack+temp);
        **//testSize(stack,stack_size,top);**
        return result;
    }
    printf("%d top \n",*top);
    return 0;
}
void testSize(double *stack, int *stack_size, int * top) //size operation
{
    if(*top==*stack_size) //see if it is full
    {
        stack=(double*)realloc(stack,(*stack_size)*sizeof(double)*2); //expand size reallocate memory
        *stack_size=*stack_size*2;
    }else if(*top<*stack_size/2)
    {
        //shrink
    }
}

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{

  double* my_stack = NULL;
  int my_top = 0;
  int stack_size=2; //initial dynamic array size
  my_stack=initialize(&my_top); //initial size of 2

    int p;
    for(p=0;p<10;++p)
        push(my_stack,&my_top,p+0.1,&stack_size);

    pop(my_stack,&my_top,stack_size);


    printf("%d elements total \nDynamic current stack size %d \n",my_top,stack_size); //summary

//print stack
    int i;
    for(i=my_top-1; i>=0; --i)
    {
        printf("%f \n", *(my_stack+i));
    }

      free(my_stack);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: why tagged as C++? And, have you tried using a debugger, like gdb? And, don't case malloc

Comment: Use debugger, walk a stack near crash watching variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pop()` function takes an `int*` as the 3rd parameter, but you're passing an `int` in the following line:

```
pop(my_stack, &my_top, stack_size);
```

Should be:

```
pop(my_stack, &my_top, &stack_size);
```

So in `testSize()` when you try to de-reference this non-pointer the program crashes.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
pop(my_stack,&my_top,stack_size);
```

should be

```
pop(my_stack,&my_top,&stack_size); /* take address of stack_size with '&' */
```

I suggest you compile with the `-Wall` option and look for warnings, then eliminate them. This will not only improve your coding style but help you find this sort of thing quickly.